# What is the difference between Websphere Portal's five editions?

Tags: websphere, portal

Does anybody know what's the difference between Websphere Portal's five Editions: WebSphere Portal Server, WebSphere Portal Enable, WebSphere Portal Enable for z/OS, WebSphere Portal Extend, and WebSphere Portal Express?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

1. The code is exactly the same, but the bundle is different.
2. WebSphere Portal Express is designed for small business.
3. WebSphere Portal Enable and WebSphere Portal Extend are for large busniess and for large scale deployment.
4. WebSphere Portal Express installs and configures DB2.
5. WebSphere Portal Enable and WebSphere Portal Extend comes with derby, and you have to configure it with other databases.
6. WebSphere Portal Express has a different license package from WebSphere Portal Enable or WebSphere Portal Extend.
7. The license forbids clustering with WebSphere Portal Express. Portal Express v8 does allow for an Idle Standby cluster server with purchase of a special add-on license; however, the idle server must be set to "backup" mode in the Web Server plugin - essentially not allowing end user traffic to use the server unless the primary server is unavailable.
8. The license allows clustering with WebSphere Portal Enable and WebSphere Portal Extend.
9. WebSphere Portal Extend is bundled with the Lotus Collaborative Component CDs.
10. WebSphere Portal Enable is not bundled with the Lotus Collaborative Component CDs.
11. WebSphere for Z/OS has different CDs, because it is for mainframes and that is true for both WebSphere Portal enable for Z/OS and WebSphere Portal Extend for Z/OS.
12. When you see the phrase "WebSphere Portal" that means any WebSphere Portal family except that for WebSphere Portal Express or WebSphere Portal for Z/OS.